# Insufficient Privleges while delivering content

Tags: content, contentversion

I am having trouble delivering an existing content file. I am unable get any of files while performing a search. I am able to deliver content if i am uploading the file instead of searching for it. It certainly looks like some permission issue. The user is a System administrator profile so has access to Content.

[image]

[image]

I am using a Link in VF page which basically mimics the url that Deliver Content button does, except that it preselects the document to deliver but it throws an Insufficient Privileges error.

```
/udd/ContentDistribution/wiz/details.apexp?versionId=06850000002oplD&whatId=0065000000XZqYw
```

[image]

These work well in dev org, but throws error in an deployed org. I would think its an permission issue but cant figure out which permission.

All the content are part of a library which the user has Library Admin access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i thought it was a permission issue.

We need to provide permissions for library Administrator

- -Setup | Customize | Salesforce Files | Content Permissions
- -Click Edit for "Library Administrator"
- -Check actions to deliver Content